# How can Core Data store an NSData?

Tags: iphone, core-data

The documentation says, that core data properties can only store NSString, NSNumber and NSDate types. However, a lot of Core Data users claim Core Data could also store an NSData type. But I wasn't able to see that in the documentation, although the Xcode Data Modeler allows to choose a data type called "binary" (which seems to be NSData).

Did I miss something? Is there a hidden place in the documentation that indeed lists NSData for binary stuff?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to the [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/cocoa/Reference/CoreDataFramework/Classes/NSAttributeDescription_Class/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/NSBinaryDataAttributeType), NSData is supported as an attribute type for Core Data.  You should be able to use it without problems.

Comment: my eyes jumped over that. in multiple other places they only mention anything else but NSData. strange.

Comment: I have to admit it took me a while to find where it mentioned NSData explicitly.

Answer (score 3):

Please review [my answer to your other nearly identical question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3030049/455016) regarding binary size in the model.

Comment: thumbs up for the +1, and +1 by myself. Nice to have a Core Data guru here :)

Comment: Please provide a link otherwise I feel like i'm not visiting SO anymore but former tech forums with annoying "google is your friend" kind of answer :)