# NSData in CoreData is not saving properly

Tags: ios, core-data, ios6, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I am currently trying to store images I download from the web into an NSManagedObject class so that I don't have to **redownload** it every single time the application is opened. I currently have these two classes.

Plant.h

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * name;
@property (nonatomic, retain) PlantPicture *picture;
```

PlantPicture.h

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * bucketName;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * creationDate;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSData * pictureData;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * slug;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * urlWithBucket;
```

Now I do the following:

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    PlantCollectionCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
    Plant *plant = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    cell.plantLabel.text = plant.name;

    if(plant.picture.pictureData == nil)
    {
        NSLog(@"Downloading");
        NSMutableString *pictureUrl = [[NSMutableString alloc]initWithString:amazonS3BaseURL];
        [pictureUrl appendString:plant.picture.urlWithBucket];
        NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:pictureUrl]];        

        AFImageRequestOperation *imageOperation = [AFImageRequestOperation imageRequestOperationWithRequest:request success:^(UIImage *image) {
            cell.plantImageView.image = image;
            plant.picture.pictureData = [[NSData alloc]initWithData:UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 1.0)];
            NSError *error = nil;
            if (![_managedObjectContext save:&error]) {
                NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
            }
        }];
        [imageOperation start];
    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"Already");
        cell.plantImageView.image = [UIImage imageWithData:plant.picture.pictureData];
    }
    NSLog(@"%@", plant.name);
    return cell;
}
```

The plant information is present, as well as the picture object. However, the NSData itself is NEVER saved throughout the application opening and closing. I always have to REDOWNLOAD the image! Any ideas!? [Very new to CoreData... sorry if it is easy!]

thanks!

**Edit & Update:**

The image download is NOT nil and appears just fine after it was downloaded. It looks like the data returned by UIImageJPEGRepresentation is not nil also. My managedObjectContext is not nil as well. The request is done on the main-thread according to my debugger. Anything else I should check?!

Also, if I quit the view and come back, the images **won't be downloaded again** and the "Already" log will appear. However, if I close and reopen the app, they will have to be redownloaded, which is weird because the rest of the CoreData is still present.

```
NSFetchedResultsController *aFetchedResultsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest managedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext sectionNameKeyPath:nil cacheName:@"Master"];
```

**Update #2**

It appears that all my ManagedObjectContext are the same. Could it have to do with the cache?

[image]

Comment: Could You give some more information?
The image downloaded is not nil? Is the completion block handled in a background thread or in the main thread? _managedObjectContext not nil for sure? And be careful UIImageJPEGRepresentation() may return nil...

Comment: Hmm are you using the same managedObjectContext in the fetchedResultsController? I am asking because you are accessing it once with _moc but at the creation of the resultsController via self.moc?

Comment: They appear to be the same... but still not working. See update #2.

Comment: Is this the only MOC you are using in your app? Because if its for example a child context of your main context maybe you forgot to merge and save the parent?!

Comment: It is the only one. God damnit.. what the hell :S. Now.. I just tried with a simple User Object that I have. I got the object, changed the firstname, saved it, closed the app and re-opened it. Still, the name hasn't changed. The first time I create my data is via RestKit... but then it seems like I am having trouble altering the data :S

Comment: I do not know much about restkit, but it seems that you are changing the objects just in memory. Be sure that you initialise the RestKit objects with the same MOC you are using in your viewController (I think I remember restkit subclasses NSManagedObject and that restkit objects need a context)

Comment: You were right. I found this. http://restkit.org/api/0.20.0/Classes/RKManagedObjectStore.html#//api/name/mainQueueManagedObjectContext so I had two object contexts, and the one I used was the children. Now... I just don't know which one to always use :S ! Thanks!

Comment: If you cannot inject your own MOC to the RestKit Framework your only option is to use the one managed by the framework.
I do not like that very much. IMHO restkit would "do to much" for me, if it can not use my context...

Answer (score 0):

First thing to check, is `plant` or `plant.picture` nil after fetch? Second, you say that the request is made on the main thread and that your context is not nil. However, the response(inside the block) is it on the main thread? From the code you shared I would say `plant.picture` is nil, but other things are possible too.

Answer (score -2):

You need to make sure that `pictureData` should have type `transformable`
And also in your class you need `pictureData` to be id not `NSData`

Like this

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) id pictureData;
```

Comment: Why should pictureData be Transformable? You can easily save an Image via NSData into coredata. No need for transformable!

Comment: you don't need to make pictureData of type **id**. NSData works just fine http://stackoverflow.com/a/2988871